# Send value from .php to .js

Tags: javascript, php

I am having a little bug that is making me crazy, I have looked all over the internet and find many different solutions but non of the works for me. I have 
one php file and one js file, I am trying to send value from the php to js.

PHP:

```
$_SESSION['url'] = '\''.$url.'\'';
```

JS:

```
var url="<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['url']) ?>";
    var webPage = require('webpage');
    var page = webPage.create();

    page.open(url, function(status) {
        console.log(url);
        phantom.exit();
    });
```

I have tried to output the url value and it is empty, so what am I doing wrong, keep in mind the js file is .js

Comment: when you do a View Source on the .js file, what do you see?

Answer (score 0):

PHP code is not being executed in .js files. In order to assign this url variable you need to get it via ajax or set it in the head section of your layout.

Comment: JS files is a static content (like images). PHP doesn't interpret images, right?

Comment: You clearly missed the point of an interpreter, I asked _what if JavaScript goes through the PHP compiler_ ..

Comment: I'm going to keep being a sane man and don't answer that. Thank you for the conversation.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you do too complicated. Let's try code:

```
<?
$url = 'http://example.com';
$a = '\''.$url.'\'';
?>
var url="<?php echo json_encode($a) ?>";<br>
var url="<?php echo $url; ?>";
```

return:

```
var url=""'http:\/\/example.com'"";
var url="http://example.com";
```

Answer (score 0):

I think should remove all quotes from your code and ensure session_start() function must be the very first thing in your document. Before any HTML tags.

PHP:

```
$_SESSION['url'] = $url;
```

JS:

```
var url='<?php echo $_SESSION['url'] ?>';
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();

page.open(url, function(status) {
    console.log(url);
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: Still have to start and close the `session`

Answer (score 0):

Please change your .js  file to .php and then under script tag put your js code.

Answer (score 0):

You have to let PHP interpret the `session` value, this can be done in various ways.

First of all, you can just set the `$url` without quotes

```
<?php
  session_start();
  // no idea why you encode as JSON.
  $_SESSION['url'] = json_encode($url);
  session_write_close();
?>
```

One is using a `script` tag of some `.php` file, e.g. the `index.php` file.

```
<script>
<?php
  session_start();
  $session_url = $_SESSION['url'];
  session_write_close();
?>
var url='<?php echo $session_url ?>',
    webPage = require('webpage'),
    page = webPage.create();

    page.open(url, function(status) {
        console.log(url);
        phantom.exit();
    });
</script>
```

Second option is generating the javascript as source, e.g.

```
<script src="javascript.php"></script>
```

Where `javascript.php` supplies the same code as the first example, by only applying the header content-type.

```
<?php
  header('Content-Type: application/javascript');
  session_start();
  $session_url = $_SESSION['url'];
  session_write_close();
?>
var url='<?php echo $session_url ?>',
    webPage = require('webpage'),
    page = webPage.create();

    page.open(url, function(status) {
        console.log(url);
        phantom.exit();
    });
```